# Import csv to mysql via php first line has 0

Tags: mysql, csv, import

i import via php a csv file to mysql, this is the code:

```
 $file = fopen(file.csv, 'r');
 while(($data = fgetcsv($file, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE){

mysql_query( "INSERT INTO tabletest
                    VALUES ('',
                            '".$data[0]."',
                            '".$data[1]."',
                            '".$data[2]."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

The file.csv only has 3 columns and is this:

10412;2015-05-23;1032.75
10412;2015-08-23;1032.75
10412;2015-11-23;1032.75
10949;2012-10-08;110.0

When import, the first line and second column is 0

1 | 0 | 2015-05-23 | 1032.75
2 | 10412 | 2015-08-23 | 1032.75
3 | 10412 | 2015-11-23 | 1032.75
4 | 10949 | 2012-10-08 | 110.0

thank a help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as follows:

- was to bring a value '?'  before the number.

I removed with the following command:

```
$value = substr($data[0], 3);
```